# Android MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() return 0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

```
       Runnable updateSeekbar=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while (true) {
                    if (!isPlayerDead) {
                        Log.d("Threads", "Thread is running successfully.");
                        int progress=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                        Log.d("Seekbar",seekBar.getProgress()+"");
                        Log.d("MediaProgress",mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+"");
                        String s=modifyTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60) + ":" + modifyTime((mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) % 60);
                        progressTime.setText(s);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Executor executor=new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            Thread thread=new Thread(command);
            thread.start();
        }
    };
executor.execute(updateSeekbar);
```

> I am making a mediaplayer to play audio but when I try to update seekbar using mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition it always returns 0.

How can I get the current position of mediaplayer?**strong text**

Comment: I was just having a similar problem, but I'm not sure it is the same situation. In my case I had a stop method that was calling player.seekTo(0); player.stop(). The thing is that the seek could fail to complete (I guess if the stop was called too fast), which you can verify by setting the setOnSeekCompleteListener, and if it failed to complete then the currentPosition would stop incrementing on every subsequent calls to player.start().

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your while loop:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        duration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
         seekBar.setProgress(progress);
         Log.d("Seekbar",seekBar.getProgress()+"");
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't worked for me. Actually the problem is little different. The thread dies before the mediaplayer can send updated position. I have made the thread in an. Endless while loop but still it dies. How can I make it run infinitely till the activity gets destroyed.

Comment: No actually the thread died beacause of improper try catch{} but not I have placed the try catch{} block inside while loop and it's working fine. Thanks for your help!